# Detailed Billing information for AWS/S3 Storage and Bandwidth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have thousands of customers with resources being stored on AWS/S3.  I want to be able to see how much bandwidth and storage those customers are costing me.  I can't use buckets since that is limited to 100.  I can't use tags because that is limited to 10/bucket.  What strategy can I use to get the information I need to track costs?

Just to be clear: We are hosting their content. They upload it to us, we store it on AWS. I can track a lot of things, but something like a partial download, can only be reported by AWS.

Comment: I believe you'll have to parse aws logs to get this info. To simplify parsing you could use e.g. one "folder" per user in your bucket. Can you tell little more about usecase?

Comment: I don't see any aws logs that contain that information?

Comment: you may need to turn on [detailed billing reports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/detailed-billing-reports.html#turnonreports) for this

Comment: I can't find any reports that actually include the file or directory of the file being accessed.

Comment: what about S3 access logs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html

Comment: @mojo you would think, right? No where in there do they include anything that tells you the file being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a breakdown per customer, you can give each user their own [IAM user](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) - with this, you should be able to get per-user information, or even assign different permissions to the different users/groups.

This is of course assuming that you aren't doing user management yourself - in that case, you should be able to record your own usage metrics with the currently logged in user and the S3 APIs you're calling.

Comment: My customers don't have or need their own login. We just host content and would like to allocate storage and bandwidth. Any way we could even see it broken down by file? Directory?

Comment: If your users are calling S3 directly, and you don't manage them as users, then everything will be run as the same (probably root) user.  __It's also very dangerous, as it gives a lot of unnecessary power to your thousands of users.__  You won't be able to get more detailed (per bucket/file) without running your own regular queries that knows about those buckets/files and checks their size. That would be useful for general information, but not consistent enough for billing your customers.

Comment: We are hosting their content. They upload it to us, we store it on AWS. I can track a lot of things, but something like a partial download, can only be reported by AWS.